# How do you reset counters?

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to reset the counter that appears next to equations in `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{align}` so that my last homework problem doesn't refer to an equation several lines up as equation 42. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT:

Due to the need to adhere to a template, I can't use sections and therefore `\numberwithin`cannot be used

EDIT #2:

The template is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top = 1.5in, left = 1in, right = 1in, bottom = 1.5in]  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}    

\title{}
\author{Author}     
\date{\today}               

\makeatletter               
\let\Author\@author         
\let\Date\@date             
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Problem}{\relax}
\newcounter{problemcount}
\newcommand{\nextproblem}[1]{\renewcommand{\Problem}{#1}\setcounter{equation {0}\setcounter{page}{0}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\Problem}
\chead{}
\rhead{
\Author
\\
Class
\\
Section
\\
\Date
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{56.2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nextproblem{Problem 1}
\begin{proof}\begin{align*}1+1&=2\\2&=2\end{align*}\end{proof}
\newpage

\nextproblem{Problem 2}\begin{proof}\begin{align*}1+1&=2\\2&=2\end{align*}\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always use `\setcounter{thecounter}{0}`

Comment: `\setcounter{equation}{0}` as Sean Allred wrote

Comment: Alternatively,there is a `\@addtoreset`, for example in a subsection possible, but this depends on the structures of the home work document

Comment: I wasn't sure of the name of the counter. Though now my problem is getting the header to format correctly.

Comment: It's called an XY problem. You ask for X but in fact you need to solve Y. Better post your Y instead.

Comment: You've posted a template, but it's not clear *which* counter is giving you problems. Is it the counter for equations? If so, what exactly is the current problem, and how would you like to see it fixed?

Comment: This is not a template, it's a pile-up of commands, scratched from a dozens of other 'templates' ;-) And the solution suggested by U. Martinez - Corral should work for this too, I suppose  -- `\nextproblem` --> `\renewcommand{\Problem}`????

Comment: Link to new question about conditionals. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202422/is-there-a-way-to-have-different-behavior-for-even-pages-and-odd-pages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you describe each problem in a different section, you may have a look at the [`numberwithin`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#numberwithin) command provided in the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. For example: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`. It just does `\setcounter{equation}{0}` automatically.

Comment: Not what I was looking for. Due to the need to adhere to a template, I can't use vanilla sections.

Comment: @alphadelta: You should rather provide this 'template' instead of letting users making educated guesses. In principle, the solution by U.Martinez-Corral should work in any well - behaving template or `.cls` file ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yeah. +1 upvote for good answer that fits most cases.

Comment: @alphadelta +1ing is fine but either mark this as not-accepted or ask a new question. Your question will get much less attention if you have accepted an answer since people will assume that you already have a suitable solution and there is no puzzle left to solve.

Comment: @alphadelta Of course, that's assuming that your edits to the question are accurate. Judging from the comments, I'm not clear whether this solution worked for you in the end or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your code did not compile as is. I made some corrections, and added the necessary lines in order to get what you want. If I understand well, page numbers are reset at every problem, as are the equation numbers.

The latter problem is addressed by loading the `chngcntr` package, which allows to reset a counter whenever any chosen counter changes. However, this doesn't work with the page counter, but simply adding the `\page numbering{arabic}` in the code that defines the `\nextproblem` command does the job.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top = 1.5in, left = 1in, right = 1in, bottom = 1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\title{}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\let\Author\@author
\let\Date\@date
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Problem}{\relax}
\newcounter{problemcount}
\setcounter{problemcount}{0}

\newcommand{\nextproblem}[1]{\clearpage\stepcounter{problemcount}\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\Problem}{#1}}
\counterwithin*{equation}{problemcount}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\Problem}
\chead{}
\rhead{
\Author
\\
Class
\\
Section
\\
\Date
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{56.2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nextproblem{Problem 1}
\begin{proof}\begin{align}1+1&=2\\2&=2\end{align}\end{proof}
\newpage

\nextproblem{Problem 2}
\begin{proof}\begin{align}1+1&=2\\2&=2\end{align}\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]